# How to force Retrofit2 to produce the exact desired output, preferrably avoiding manual serialization into a RequestBody parameter type?

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

The unit test that follows emits this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5

"123"
```

What I need is this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18

{ "data" : "123" }
```

(remove the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, and produce proper json). Is there a way to achieve it without manually serializing into a `RequestBody` parameter type?

Here is the code:

```
class Result{}

interface Proxy {
    @Multipart
    @POST("MethodName")
    Call<Result> SendData(@Part("data")String data);
}

public class Retrofit2QuestionTest {
    @Test
    public void Test() {
        // This is for Fiddler:
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");

        final Object sync = new Object();

        Proxy proxy = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.1/acme/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(Proxy.class);

        Call<Result> call = proxy.SendData("123");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, retrofit2.Response<Result> response) {
                try {
                    printCallData(call, response);
                } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                finally { sync.notifyAll(); }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                try {
                    printCallData(call, null);
                    System.err.println("onFailure");
                } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                finally { sync.notifyAll(); }
            }

            private void printCallData(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) throws IOException {
                Buffer sink = new Buffer();
                call.request().body().writeTo(sink);
                String actualBody = sink.readUtf8();
                int code = response != null ? response.code() : -1;
                System.out.println(String.format("Code: %d\r\nBody:\r\n%s", code, actualBody));
            }
        });

        synchronized (sync) {
            try {
                sync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Test ended.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make `http://192.168.1.1/acme/MethodName` produce the desired output so that Retrofit can parse it accordingly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I don't understand what you're saying. This is my question - how do I make it produce the output I want it to produce. Did you mean that I must use `RequestBody`?

Comment: The server returns a string. You expect a JSON. The server should return the JSON. Retrofit doesn't really have anything to do with what your server returns beyond parsing what your server returns.